Using userDataDir deletes all existing Chrome data in Puppeteer
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    userDataDir: "/Users/[user-name]/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome",
  });

I am using Puppeteer, and I am utilizing userDataDir so that when a new window opens, the login status is maintained. Although the code works correctly, when I run the code, it seems to delete all the existing Chrome configuration files (as if it's resetting them).
I am asking because it seems beyond my capability.

I'm not sure what you mean by this. If it's deleting all of your Chrome config files, that doesn't really sound like "working correctly". Can you clarify a bit what you're trying to do, and what the actual behavior is? Thanks.

Does this answer your question? How to pass userDataDir profile folder to Puppeteer
